# Annotations not working in Okular (missing characters)

Tags: fedora, kde, plasma5, okular

Yesterday, I upgraded to Fedora 34 from a F33 install.

Today, while using Okular (KDE's PDF reader), I noticed that special characters (áéíóúç etc...) doesn't appear in annotations made within the PDF. For example, in the image below, I should be getting 'xxx áéíóú xxx' rather than 'xxx xxx'.

[image]

What can be causing this problem? I don't recall it happening in F33.

Comment: It is [a known bug and I opened an issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1954140).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a [bug in poppler](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1958673) which is already solved. The fix will soon be available in Fedora's repos.